# How to add third party plugin jquery on angular 7?

Tags: jquery, angular, angular7

Hi I´ve been trying to add a third party jquery plugin on my App Angular 7. So far I´ve done: Added in angular.json the location of files like this:

```
"scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "src/assets/js/ticker/jquery.easy-ticker.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
 ]
```

In my AppComponent:

```
declare var $: any; interface JQuery { easyTicker(options?: any):
JQuery; }
```

Try to execute:

```
 ngAfterViewInit() {

    $('.ultimasExecucoes').easyTicker({
      visible: 1,
      interval: 4000
    });
}
```

In my template

```
<div class="ultimasExecucoes">
            <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let workFlow of execucoesEncerradas"> 
                {{workFlow.nomeWorkFlow}} - Data Início: {{workFlow.dataInicioWf | date : 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'}} 
                - Data Encerramento: {{workFlow.dataEncerramentoWf | date : 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'}} 
                - Resultado: {{workFlow.resultadoExecucao}}
            </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

But nothing happens on my page. How can I add the plugin jquery ?

Comment: Can you share also the template? It is hard to tell what is wrong unless seeing the template.

Comment: You need to add more details to your question. Most likely this isn't working though due to the way you are trying to access the element. A better way would be to utilize something like `@ViewChild('.ultimasExecucoes'): ElementRef;`

Comment: How can I use @ViewChild ?

Comment: I tried a lot of things and I catch this error on console: ERROR TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7__(...).easyTicker is not a function
    at ExecucoesEncerradasComponent.push../src/app/execucoes-encerradas/execucoes-encerradas.component.ts.ExecucoesEncerradasComponent.ngAfterViewInit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi after I read a many articles about jquery types I solved this issue like this:

1. First you need to install jquery/types: npm install --save @types/jquery
2. Inside directory nodes_modules/@types I created a folder "easyticker"(name of plugin)
3. Into directory "easyticker" I created file: index.d.ts inside I put this:

> declare module 'easyTicker'
>
> interface JQuery {   easyTicker(options?: any): JQuery; }

4. On my Component I imported jquery:

> import * as jQuery from 'jquery'

5. Then I called my plugin:

> ngAfterViewInit() {
>
> ```
>   /* JqueryEasyTicker */
>   (<any>$)( document ).ready(function() {
>       (<any>$)('#ultimasExecucoes').easyTicker({
>         visible: 1,
>         interval: 8000
>       });
>   });   
>  }
> ```