# Javascript/Jquery : fail to include function in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I'm trying to use a french datepicker in angular but I'm not able to call the function inside my component.

***datefrench.js***

```
!function(datefrench){datefrench.fn.datepicker.dates.fr={

days:["dimanche","lundi","mardi","mercredi","jeudi","vendredi","samedi"],
daysShort:["dim.","lun.","mar.","mer.","jeu.","ven.","sam."],
daysMin:["d","l","ma","me","j","v","s"],
months:["janvier","février","mars","avril","mai","juin","juillet","août","septembre","octobre","novembre","décembre"],
monthsShort:["janv.","févr.","mars","avril","mai","juin","juil.","août","sept.","oct.","nov.","déc."],
today:"Aujourd'hui",
monthsTitle:"Mois",
clear:"Effacer",
weekStart:1,
format:"dd/mm/yyyy"}}(jQuery);
```

***add-date.component.ts***

```
  import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormControl, Validators, Form } from '@angular/forms';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    
    declare var datefrench;
    declare var $:any;
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-add-date',
      templateUrl: './add-date.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./add-date.component.css']
    })
    export class AddDateComponent implements OnInit {
    
    
      constructor(private router: Router) { }
    
      ngOnInit() {
        $(function () {
        $('#mydate').datepicker({
         language: 'fr'})
        });
        }
    }
```

***add-date.component.html***

```
<input type="text" id="mydate" name="mydate">
```

but it keeps saying the the function datepicker is not recognized.

***PS: all assets(javascript/css..) are included correctly***

Comment: I think you need to use `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle instead of `ngOnInit`.

Comment: still didn't work

Comment: can you provide a playground (codesandbox, repl.it)?

Comment: Show how you included the script and the exact error message

Answer (score 0):

You could be not added the script path in the `angular.json`'s related `scripts` section.

Basically when adding third-party javascript which does not support ES6 modules the steps are:

1. Install the script and related dependencies with `npm install` -> `npm install jquery npm install myJqueryPlugin`
2. Install types of the jquery plugin when using typescript. This is important also, and if types does not exist, you could manually create like shown in [How to add third party plugin jquery on angular 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55495179/how-to-add-third-party-plugin-jquery-on-angular-7)
3. Check `"types": [ "jquery", "whatever" ]` in the `tsconfig.app.json`
4. In the `angular.json` or `angular-cli.json` it should be added in the scripts section. This step is important, try this first.

```js
"scripts": [
  "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.js",
  "others ie. jquery plugin in your case with correct path"
]
```

5. It is made available in the `window` object like `window['datefrench']`.
6. Or instead of step #5 use with `declare var $;` as you did.